# Initialize MongoClient with MongoClientSettings in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm trying to initialize the MongoClient from the Mongo 2.0 driver as follows:

```
MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
settings.WaitQueueSize = int.MaxValue;
settings.WaitQueueuTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,2,0);
settings.MinConnectionPoolSize = 1;
settings.MaxConnectionPoolSize = 25;
settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("mongodb://localhost");
client = new MongoClient(settings)
```

However, when I now try to insert a document with this code:

```
db = client.GetDatabase("local");
col = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
col.InsertOneAsync(new BsonDocument().Add(new BsonElement("id",BsonValue.Create(1)))).Wait();
```

It doesn't do anything. It doesn't get inserted, and no error message (although after a while a first chance exception of System.Timeout appears in the output). If I initialize the client with

```
client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
```

It does work and uploads the document as intended.

I want the client to be able to handle a very high write throughput, so I tried these settings first. Did I set some of the settings wrong or is there a different problem?

EDIT: After some more testing, it is indeed a System.Timeout exception I'm getting.

Comment: Do you wait for the async execution using `await`, `Wait()` or `.Result`?

Comment: Yes I do, I edited the code to reflect that

Comment: Have you tried with the default settings?

Comment: Yes, I tried with `client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")` and it works

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem, only in my error message, there is some much more helpful information buried somewhere in about 40 lines of text:

> No such host is known

It turns out that `MongoServerAddress` [only expects the hostname, not the protocol](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoServerAddress.cs):

```
settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost");
```

Answer (score 0):

I m doing it like this:

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl("mongodb://localhost"));
settings.WaitQueueSize = int.MaxValue;
settings.WaitQueueuTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,2,0);
settings.MinConnectionPoolSize = 1;
settings.MaxConnectionPoolSize = 25;
client = new MongoClient(settings)
```